# How to update all profiles with the same Custom Object Permissions?

Tags: permissions, profile

The case:
I created a custom object. After that, I need to give permissions to all profiles. I have a lot of profiles. And editing each one is time-consuming.
Is there a way to update all profiles at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Field Level Security:

Setup > Security Controls > Field Accessibility > Select `Object Name` > Select `View by Fields`

You can then edit permissions for each field by profile, one field at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The way to do this in 2019 is to create a custom **Profile List View** and edit Object Permissions en masse.

See the Salesforce documentation of the process here: [Edit Multiple Profiles with Profile List Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_inline_editing.htm&type=5)

> If enhanced profile list views are enabled for your organization, you can change permissions in up to 200 profiles directly from the list view, without accessing individual profile pages.